# Will this setup work? (Parse-Server/DigitalOcean)

Tags: architecture, digital-ocean, parse-server

[image]

Will the following setup work?:

- (DigitalOcean) Load Balancer
- 2 identical Parse-Server instances (same config, cloud code, etc.)
- 1 MongoDB instance

I am worried about potential session-related issues, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sessions are managed in the database, you don’t have to worry about them! That should work very well and you can scale horizontally with this pattern with very few hurdles

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as you configure the load balancer properly, this should definitely work. As @flovilmart said, this setup is also scalable horizontally.

Regarding session, it is managed in db so you don't have to worry but I would recommend you to use **JWT** tokens instead of session. This will remove your dependency on server-side session and thus in the future if you plan to scale horizontally it would be easier for you to do so.